# Matplotlib: misalignment between barh and boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm ploting a barh and a boxplot using subplots, with the python library matplotlib.
I'm currently using the code below:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10,5))
# Just some random data for reproducibility 
barg_data = [10,15,18,10,15,18,10,15,18,10,15,18]
barh_labels = ['adjiosajd', 'jsajdoiasd', 'sadasdad', 'adjiosajd',
           'jsajdoiasd', 'sadasdad','adjiosajd', 'jsajdoiasd',
           'sadasdad','adjiosajd', 'jsajdoiasd', 'sadasdad']

boxplot_data = [[1,3,2],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,3,2],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],
            [1,3,2],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,3,2],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
boxplot_labels = ['asdasdaff', 'sanasjdn', 'oskfoad','asdasdaff',
              'sanasjdn', 'oskfoad','asdasdaff', 'sanasjdn',
              'oskfoad','asdasdaff', 'sanasjdn', 'oskfoad']

ax[0].set_title('Barh')
ax[0].barh(range(len(barh_labels)), barg_data, tick_label=barh_labels)

ax[1].boxplot(boxplot_data, vert=False, labels=boxplot_labels)
ax[1].set_title("Boxplot")
```

And I'm obtain this result:

[Barh and Boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1exSt.png)

It's noticeable that the bar starts to shows the bars after the boxplot. I looked for the documentation but I couldn't find any parameter to fix it.

I tried to use the sharey in the subplots definition but it's resulting in label overlapping, image from the result below:

[barh and boxplot with sharey=True](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPC5L.png)

Comment: can you provide the dataset you used, for a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Did you try `fig, ax = plt.subplots(..., sharey=True)`?

Comment: @JohanC indeed the sharey parameter aligned the grid between the subplots, but it's generating a label overlapping, do you know how can I fix this behaviour? I added some example in the post.

Comment: @Snehil added some example data for reproducibility.

Comment: `fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4)`　The label overlap can now be eliminated.

Comment: @r-beginners unfortunately i couldn't reach the expected result using this parameter with "sharey=True", even adding some extra space. Could you add an example that this solution works?